# Bash syntax error executing command in Ruby, but it works in shell

Tags: ruby, linux, bash

Here is the command (the one I'm using is a slight variation of it, but this produces the same error)

```
HTTP_STATUS=$(curl -w "%{http_code}" -o >(cat >&3) 'http://example.org')
```

As for what this does, it's mostly copied from https://superuser.com/a/862395/334171 ... the point is to print the output of a HTTP request to the terminal, but store the status code in a bash variable. This works fine if I run it in terminal.

However, I get `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` when I run it from Ruby:

```
cmd = <<-SH
  HTTP_STATUS=$(curl -w "%{http_code}" -o >(cat >&3) 'http://example.org')
SH
system cmd
`#{cmd}`
```

both of these fail with the aformentioned error.

I suppose as a workaround I could put in a shell script and call that from Ruby. But I'm curious why it's not working in the inline fashion.

Comment: `>(cat >&3)` is bash syntax. Make sure you execute this command in `bash` from `Ruby`

Comment: @anubhava As you can see from my last code snippet, I'm trying to do that using both backticks and `system`. Also, it is Bash executing the code, which is evident from the `sh: ` at the beginning of the error indicating it's coming from bash.

Comment: Try: `system("bash", "-c", cmd)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**bash** behaves differently when you run using the name `sh` so `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` will behave differently even when `/bin/sh` really is `/bin/bash`. In particular, when **bash** is run as `sh`, it conforms as closely as possible to the POSIX specification so **bash**-specific extensions (such as your `>(cat >&3)`) won't work. Furthermore, backticks and related methods in Ruby always use the system shell (i.e. `/bin/sh`). In summary: if you're using a shell from within Ruby then you'll almost always end up using a strictly POSIX shell.

You could explicitly invoke `/bin/bash` and use `-c` to feed it commands. This will probably involve a nightmare of escaping though.

Better would be to bypass the shell (all of them) by using [`Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) from the Ruby standard library. There are various methods in `Open3` for capturing and piping the standard output and standard error and you won't have to worry about shell-quoting anything because there won't be a shell involved.

BTW, if you're really trying to set an environment variable through backticks or `system`, it won't work as environment variables are local to the child process so the parent (your Ruby script or whatever invoked your Ruby script) will never see them.

Comment: I'm trying `Open3.popen3(cmd) do |i,o,e,t|` ... still getting the syntax error when I do `e.read`

Comment: I suppose it'd be better to use rest client or something. but I still have curiosity as to how to make my previous approach work.

Comment: You wouldn't need any of the redirection stuff with `Open3`, the pipes take care of that. And you'd want to `Open3.popen3('curl', '-w', ...)` to keep shells out of the picture.